# Trying to post raw html data in angularjs $http, getting $sce trust error

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I'm working on a CMS site in angularjs + ASP.NET MVC, need to post a raw html string to server side, its throwing

> [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Already tried content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, `JSON.stringify(postdata)` and all. But none works.

```
$http.post({
    url: '/xxx/yyyy',
    data: $scope.NewMessage, // Raw HTML string - "<div><p>test</p></div>"
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallBack(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Please include stack trace and code for the [$sce:itype](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/itype) error.

Comment: For form encoded you need a key/value string like `data: 'html=' + htmlString`

Comment: And url encoding requires certain characters in the `htmlString` to be percent encoded. It is not a wise choice for sending HTML.

Comment: Right...per@georgeawg comment should really be `data: 'html=' + encodeURIComponent(htmlString )`

Comment: Sorry, My bad... the error occured on success call...! Just to note - No need for content-type header, or encodeURIComponent and all...!  I just wrapped my data inside a Javascript object; worked like a charm...!!!

Comment: Thank you @georgeawg :)

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl :)